# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\Documents\Eclipse' in Protractor using Eclipse

Tags: protractor

Want to run Simple Protractor program (Open Google and search for a keyword) which is working fine when I run through cmd but facing "Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\Documents\Eclipse'" issue when I try to run the same program using Eclipse

Below are the steps that were performed.
1. Created JavaScript project in Eclipse
2. Copied both spec.js and conf.js to the project 
3. Converted the project to Tern Project
4. Ran "npm install protractor" from the project location
5. Selected cli.js from Run Configuration
6. Ran conf.js which is resulting "Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\Documents\Eclipse'"

Below is the code of both conf.js and spec.js

conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
        specs: ['spec.js'],
        capabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                // disable "chrome pop-up"
                'args': ['disable-infobars=true'], 

                // disable Password manager popup
                'prefs': {
                    'credentials_enable_service': false
                }
            }
        }


}
```

spec.js

```
describe('Open Google and search for Protractor', function(){
    it('It should open Google and search for Protractor', function(){
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.get('https://google.co.in');
        browser.sleep(3000);
        var search=element(by.name('q'));
        search.sendKeys('Protractor'+protractor.Key.ENTER);
        browser.sleep(3000);

    });


});
```

Error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\username\Documents\Eclipse'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

Expecting that when I run conf.js from Eclipse, browser should be opened and search for "Protractor" keyword

Comment: Have you selected the correct "cli.js" under your protractor run configurations?
Please check once.

Comment: @NitishKshirsagar `${workspace_loc:/Demo_Protractor/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js}`
This is the path that I gave under Run Configurations